# What is the strategy for "If Living Walls Could Talk?"

Tags: tiny-heroes

What strategies can I use to get 3 stars on "If Living Walls Could Talk?" in the Opal Observatory?

I know that I should build Mana Crystals and Lava Lobbers on the magma vents, but I never seem to have enough built by the time the last wave comes, when all those Epic heroes wander on through and destroy everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, build a Baby Red Dragon, facing up, on the magma vent farthest left.  Build a Lava Lobber and a Super Mana Crystal on the magma vents at top right, starting with the right-most spots.  Then alternate between building Super Magma Crystals and Baby Red Dragons on the remaining vents, focusing the Dragons on lanes that the Heroes will walk through.

[image: In-progress screenshot of "If Living Walls Could Talk" level]

Start a Fire Blast (facing left) from the middle of the blocked Lookers and Jelly cubes.  Repeat when available.  The point of this is to destroy that Living Wall to free the Lookers and Cubes.

Drop a Living Wall in the middle of the 5th column from the right to block that path; and put a Slime in front of this wall.  keep building Mana Crystals in the open spaces at the right edge.  Any time the Lava Lobber is recharged, build one over the most protected magma vent.

Keep building Mana Crystals at the left end of the map to distract Wizards and Epic Wizards.  Drop Slimes and Skeletons here too, to kill them.

Finally, just keep trying.